# PostgreSQL preserve comments

Tags: comments, ddl

I'm relatively new to  the PostgreSQL environment, coming from years of experience in SQLServer.  Not sure if this is an environmental thing with pgAdmin or just PostgreSQL itself but I'm wondering how to preserve comments in saved SQL statements.

For example, say you create a view like

```
create view MyView
as
/*
   comment1
   comment2
   ...
*/
select    col1
          ,col2
          --,col3    -- comment line 
from      tbl1
where     1 = 1;
```

and then highlight this created view in pgAdmin (in the object browser), none of those comments appear.  You basically see something like

```
create or replace view myview as
select    col1,
          col2
from      tbl1
where     1 = 1;
```

As you can see, the comments have been removed.  Is this a config setting, am I "doing it wrong"?

Many thanks,

B

Comment: I suppose you could use the SQL COMMENT function to attach comments to schema objects. But it's more unwieldy than inline comments: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-comment.html

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've gone down that track and it's good for descriptors - a great feature actually.  However, the removal of comments overall seems a little odd.  In the example i posted, i purposely showed a commented column.  You can imagine test scenarios where a column or other snippet of code is commented out (for some time) and then reinstated.  Or more generally, commenting the code ;)

Comment: It's probably less an active removal of comments, but that the DB does not store the original SQL at all. Does it preserve other things (such as capitalization, spacing, line breaks, redundant use of schema alias, etc)?

Comment: Here's a discussion on the user group: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAAQkdDod-N6nPbCKZ12zxjmYND=8tak3cZyJN40hELEbEfcw0A@mail.gmail.com

Comment: Great link, thanks!   Looks like the advice is to use an IDE for code management, and only the admin tool for publishing.  Makes sense.  It's interesting coming from the SQLServer space in that the IDE is sort of an all-in-one experience (a la Visual Studio).  Additionally, SQLServer databases do store (or so it would seem) the original SQL content.